# Grid controls compatible with .NET and Mono?

Tags: c#, datagrid, controls, mono

Do you know any grid control compatible with .NET and Mono?

DataGridView seems to be quite buggy on Mono, and GTK# controls depends on GTK+ so you need to install it in windows machines where, usually, it's not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try out the preview of Mono 2.0.  DataGridView is vastly better in this version, though there are still several places where it is still lacking.

http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/preview/download-preview/

Answer (score 2):

I tried mono 1.9.1 (Mono 2.0 beta) and had some problems with sorting, generated columns, and some nasty exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Our grid should be compatible with Mono

see http://www.pfgrid.com

Bye
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Which version did you try? Perhaps you should give [Mono 2.0 preview](http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/preview/download-preview/) a go, it might work for you (no, the Data* controls are not yet perfect, but they have improved greatly). From my experience GTK# controls on Windows are not that great either...

Answer (score 0):

hello there if you want to try free grid controls that can work in .nt and mono, just try obout or try this links http://www.obout.com/ ok.